# Mapping resource i.e hbm.xml not found during running test in maven

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I am working on a multi module maven project . I am working on integration of spring and hibernate.

I have two modules

- Model
- Core

In the Model i have my domain objects.And i have kept the sourceUser.hbm.xml file in the model/src/main/resources/common folder.
    The corresponding model class i.e SourceUser.java is in model/src/main/java/common.

Now i have core module ,i have my application context file in core/src/main/resources folder.In the application context file i have defined data source bean and session factory bean.

Now i have one test in the core module which is correctly getting the data source bean.But when i try to get session factory object it gives below error

Tests in error:

```
testApp(org.db.AppTest): Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' define
d in class path resource [applicationContext-core.xml]: Invocation of init metho
d failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
 [classpath:common/sourceUser.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

In the pom for the core project i have added dependency for the model .I believe that during test execution its not getting model jar in the class path and hence it is not able to find the mapping resource.I have below questions

**1.** Adding the dependency of model in core, will add model project in class path of core project?

**2.** If not how to make the hbm.xml's available for core module and in test. I dont want to copy the mapping files in the core project resource folder.

Comment: is this your problem / solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/1916467/280244 ?

Comment: Yes got it thanks Ralph